# Notes collection api endpoint returning 404

Tags: api, activecollab

Is anyone able to get the notes collection api endpoint to work? It is returning a 404 for me.

When I go to `/api/v1/projects/12/notes/30`, that works correctly and `in_group` is set to `true`.

Hitting this url returns a 404 though - `/api/v1/projects/12/notes/30/collection`

Answer (score 0):

Collections as a concept has been replaced with groups (but docs were not updated accordingly when the change has been made).

Instead of going for a `collection`, get `note_group_id` from note's response, and fetch `/api/v1/projects/#PROJECT-ID#/note-groups/#NOTE-GROUP-ID#` URL.